# oledb/ado.net: Get the command's text, with all parameters replaced

Tags: ado.net, parameters, oledb

Is it possible to get the text of an `OleDbCommand` with all parameters replaced with their values? E.g. in the code below I'm looking for a way to get the query text

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE c1 = 'hello' and c2 = 'world'
```

after I finished assigning the parameters.

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE c1 = ? and c2 = ?";
var cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.WChar).Value = "hello";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.WChar).Value = "world";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No:  you have to iterate through the parameters collection yourself, doing a string.Replace() to get the equivalent.  It's particularly painful when you have to use the `?` syntax rather than the `@parametername` syntax.

The reason for this is that the full string is *never* assembled.  The parameters and sent to the server and treated as data, and are never included in the string.

All the same, I for one understand your pain.  It would have been nice if they included some kind of `.ComposeSQL()` method you could call *for debugging purposes*, that perhaps also produces a compiler warning to help avoid use in production.

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to see what query was executed and dont need to work with it programmatically, you can use SQL Profiler.